# Regex Pattern [a-zA-Z]not giving Correct Result

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

In my Android Application , I'm required to verify that the string typed by user is only 3 Characters long and has only characters from the alphabet.
Condition for 3 characters long is satisfied and working properly but the condition for checking whether the String is in the alphabet is not working.
I have attached the code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etGSTIN ;
    Button btVerify ;
    TextView tvStateName ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etGSTIN = findViewById(R.id.etGSTIN);
        btVerify = findViewById(R.id.btVerify);
        tvStateName = findViewById(R.id.btStateName);


        btVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String gstin = etGSTIN.getText().toString().trim();
                String regex = "...";

                String regex1 = "[a-zA-Z].";
                Log.d("Entered in Oclick","Entered in OnClick()");


                if(Pattern.matches(regex,gstin)){
                    Log.d("ENterd in First if","MEssage");

                 
                    if (Pattern.matches(regex1,gstin)) {
                        Log.d("Entered in Nested If","Entered in Nested IF");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verified GSTIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my first question on stack overflow. So, Please ignore if i have done any mistake in drafting the question.

Comment: Try using `[a-zA-Z]*` as your second regex

Comment: Yeah, It ([a-zA-Z]* Worked bro , Thanks a lot @GregorRant , Was stucked in this since hours :) . Can you Tell me why this Happened ?

Comment: "not working" is typically not a detailed enough description of a problem for Stack Overflow.  Please give details about your actual vs expected output and what the values of the inputs were.  Better yet, reduce the scope of your question down so that the problem is self-evident and you can ask for clarification about why there is a discrepancy.

Answer (score 5):

> Condition for 3 characters long is satisfied and working properly but
> the condition for checking whether the String is in the alphabet is
> not working.

You can use the regex, `[A-Za-z]{3}` or `\p{Alpha}{3}` which specifies 3 alphabets. Learn more about it at **[Quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)**.

This will also help you merge the following two `if` conditions

```
String regex = "...";
String regex1 = "[a-zA-Z].";    
if(Pattern.matches(regex,gstin)) { 
    if (Pattern.matches(regex1,gstin)) {
```

into a single one as shown below:

```
String regex = "[A-Za-z]{3}";// "\\p{Alpha}{3}"    
if(Pattern.matches(regex,gstin)) {
```

Your current regex, `[a-zA-Z].` is specifying a single alphabet, specified with `[a-zA-Z]` followed by any single character, specified with a dot (i.e. `.`).

Answer (score 3):

Use `^[a-zA-Z]*$` as your second regex. `^` matches the start of the string, `[a-zA-Z]` matches any alphabetic character and the `*` is a quantifier matching zero or more times of the preceding token (any alphabetic character), and the  `$` matches the end of the string (so it checks if all characters in the string satisfy the condition).

Your current regex `[a-zA-Z].` first matched any alphabetic character and then the `.` matched any character, which then matched to any alphabetic character AND any character (so needing 2 character in total).